# how to show android Keyboard automatically while Screen Opens?

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how to show the soft input keyboard while a activity opens.
In Normal case a keyboard pops up when we tap inside the edit text but i want to open it automatically when that screen loads.

here is the xml layout file

and here is the main.xml layout file

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="This is my sample App of android"
    android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="20dip">

</TextView>

<EditText android:id="@+id/EditText01" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>

<Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Say Hello"></Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute for `activity` element of AndroidManifest.xml. In your case it could be:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" ... />
```

Comment: It works for me. So your case is somehow specific and you should provide more info. Or try to create dummy test case - basic app with one activity containing single EditText and play with this attribute.

Comment: This i write in Manifest file <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> </intent-filter> </activity>

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" ... />
```

as Ralkie's answer. But to test on emulator you have to be careful in how your AVD is configured: the default configuration has keyboard support... You need to add the hardware property "Keyboard support" with "no" value on your AVD in order to test it on emulator.